# Binomial probability question!

Tags: probability, binomial-theorem

How do I solve this question?

A school lab has sixteen computers. A teacher observes that, in the long run, in 80% of school days, at least 1 machine is not working properly. Assuming the probability of a computer not working properly is independent of the others, find the probability that:

a) a randomly chosen computer is not working in any school day

b) at least 2 computers are not working properly in any school day

Attempt: I’m really not sure how to approach this question. If for 80% of school days at least 1 computer doesnt work that means for 20% of school says at least 15 doesnt work. Now do you use the binomial expansion to find for all school days?

Comment: Welcme to stackexchange. You are more likely to get answers rather than downvotes and votes to close if you [edit] the question to show us what you tried and where you are stuck. Just a question (with an exclamation point) is not the best way to get help here.

Comment: If at least one machine is not working properly on $80\%$ of school days, then on $20\%$ of school days, all the machines are working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that $0.8 = P(\text{broken PCs } \geq 1)$. So:

$$0.2 = P(\text{broken PCs } < 1) = P(\text{broken PCs }= 0) = (1-p)^{16},$$ where $p$ is the probability for the $j$-th computer to be broken. This $p$ is the answer for the first question.

For the second one: we want to calculate $q =P(\text{broken PCs } \geq 2)$. So:

$$1-q = P(\text{broken PCs } < 2) = P(\text{broken PCs }= 0) + P(\text{broken PCs }= 1) = (1-p)^{16} + \binom{16}{1}p(1-p)^{15}.$$

This $q$ is the answer to your second question.

Comment: For the second part of the question wouldn’t P(broken PCs = 1) = C(16 , 1)*[p(1-p)^15]

Comment: @RyanDavidopolous you are right! let me correct my answer